# How to implement admin access without authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I have a form to be completed by the user in the ASP.NET Core MVC project. All that needs to be done by the user is completing the form and the admin looking at the users' table with admin access decides whether to contact the user.

I know how to implement Identity or cookie/token authentication, but I was wondering how to implement authorization in this case with just one page and without authentication.

Comment: You **cannot** implement authorization *without* authentication - if you don't know **who** is running your code - how can you decide what they can do??

Comment: I know how to implement authentication, But in this case, where there is only one page I don't want the user to see any login or register button. The user just fills a form and posts it so there is no authentication, registration, or login. I don't know how to hide any login or register button so only the admin can see them and get authenticated to see all the users.

Comment: If you want the page doesn't include login or register button,you can try to use a layout doesn't contain `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />` for the page.